# Transfering data from one workbook to another after comparing data

Tags: .net, excel, vba, macos

So, we are trying to transfer the data that's in prodcode from "Book1" over to "Book2" in column "C" and it's giving us an error. Could any of you figure out why this is doing so? We've been working on it for quite some time and can't seem to figure out why.... We are still pretty new to this. 
This is what we've done.

This is the data:

[image: Image1]

This is the code that we're using:

[image: Image2]

Comment: Can you share your code, to see what you've tried?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code - copy and paste it directly into your question, and format it using the `{}` button.  Also, if you're getting an error, indicate *which line* the error occurs on.

Comment: Can you click on the links above?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this line:

```
If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, -3)
```

The offset is telling it to get information from 3 columns to the left of column "A". There is no column to the left of "A", so you're getting this error. I think you want this instead:

```
If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 3)
```